# Help In Declaring Variable Number Of Arguments

Tags: haskell, variadic, polyvariadic

High Guys,

I have to define a polymorphic datatype for a tree that can have multiple nodes. Each node can have any number of children and a vlaue.  This type will always have at least one node. I am new in Haskell so am asking how can i declare the node to have variable number of arguments.

This is what i have  now. This is a tree that can have a Node or a node with value (a) and two tree children. Instead of two tree children, i want them to be any number of tree children. (Analoog as java variable number of arguments "arg...")

```
data Tree a = Node a | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving (Show)
```

Thanks for your help

**EDIT**

A little question:::  How can i declare this node with variable arguments in a functions 
parameter(header/signature).  I have to implement a function called
"contains" which will check if a Node contains a specific element.

```
contains :: Tree a -> b -> Bool
contains (Node val [(tree)]) =   ......
```

Is the second line correct ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it would be:

```
data Tree a = Node a | Node a [(Tree a)] deriving (Show)
```

but in addition there is a second problem that this should be

```
data Tree a = Leaf a | Branch a [(Tree a)] deriving (Show)
```

or such as the parts of a union must have different names as otherwise you couldn't use pattern matching

`Leaf` and `Branch` are data constructors so:

```
Branch 1 [Leaf 3, Branch 6 [Leaf 5]]
```

is an example of a `Tree`

---

```
contains :: Tree a -> a -> Boolean 
contains (Leaf a) b = a == b
contains (Branch a c) b = a == b || any (map (\t -> contains t b) c)
```

or such

Comment: Please I have updated the main question. Can you help me solve that problem. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks  once again for your reply. Can you please explain the "any" and the "\t" to me. I understand the map function well but the "any" and "\t ." parts i don't understand them. Thanks

Comment: any returns true if any list element is true else it returns false; and as the value to check for is passed as the second arg i needed to use a lambda to reorder the args for the map

Comment: then you need to change it to `\t -> contains t b`  You could also just do `any (map (flip contains b) c)` or `any (map (\`contains\` b) c)`