# Need Help Fixing A little Bug

Tags: haskell, syntax

I posted a question today and someone helped but his code is not working. This is the link to the post [link to the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341816/help-in-declaring-variable-number-of-arguments)

When i run his code, i get an error :  "parse error on input `.'"

The "." after the "\t" is causing the error. Am new in Haskell so i don't know why it is causing the error.

Need help in resolving this but.

thanks

**UPDATE**

I get error when i load the code. this is the error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `a -> Bool'
           against inferred type `[Bool]'
    In the first argument of `any', namely
        `(map (\ t -> contains t b) c)'
    In the second argument of `(||)', namely
        `any (map (\ t -> contains t b) c)'
    In the expression: a == b || any (map (\ t -> contains t b) c)
```

need help in fixing it.

thanks

UPDATE

when i run the code after making the changes:

```
data Tree a = Leaf a | Branch a [(Tree a)] deriving (Show)

contains :: Tree a -> a -> Bool 
contains (Leaf a) b = a == b
contains (Branch a c) b = a == b or (map (\ t -> contains t b) c)
```

this is the error i now get:

```
Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type:
      a = ([Bool] -> Bool) -> [Bool] -> a
    When generalising the type(s) for `contains'
```

***UPDATE 3***

Please this is my code and yet i still get error after making all the changes. I don't understand:

```
data Tree a = Leaf a | Branch a [(Tree a)] deriving (Show)

contains :: Eq a => Tree a -> a -> Bool 
contains (Leaf a) b = a == b
contains (Branch a c) b = a == b || (map (\t -> contains t b) c)
```

The Boolean doesn't work on my system so i have to use Bool. Now this is the error i get:

```
Couldn't match expected type `Bool' against inferred type `[Bool]'
    In the second argument of `(||)', namely
        `(map (\ t -> contains t b) c)'
    In the expression: a == b || (map (\ t -> contains t b) c)
    In the definition of `contains':
        contains (Branch a c) b = a == b || (map (\ t -> contains t b) c)
```

Will you please run the above code if it will work. Or maybe am missing something somewhere.
I want to thank you soo much for your time. I appreciate it.

thanks

Comment: It was a typo, methinks (`\t . (...)` isn't valid Haskell, `\t -> (...)` is -- replacing the ellipsis with something valid, of course) and he already fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax to separate a lambda's argument list from its body in Haskell is `->`, not `.` like in lambda calculus.

Btw: this has already been fixed in the post you linked to.

Edit: He also got the usage of `any` wrong - he's treating it as if it were `or`. It needs to be either

```
or (map (\ t -> contains t b) c)
```

or

```
any (\t -> contains t b) c
```

In addition to this the type signature is wrong (`Boolean` instead of `Bool` and missing `Eq` constraint). So either remove it or change it to:

```
contains :: Eq a => Tree a -> a -> Bool
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have also fix it but then i get a new error when i run the code. I have included this new error in my post above. It has to do with the types. Need help fixing it.

Comment: i have UPDATED the post again for another error i get after making the changes

Comment: @kap: Yes, the type sig was wrong as well. This time I've actually tried to compile it and it works now.

Comment: @kap: Regarding the code you edited into your question, you shouldn't remove the `||`.

Comment: UPDATE 3.  Please i have updated the post again for another error after making the necessary changes. Hope you can help me fix it.Thanks

Comment: @kap: `map` doesn't return a `Bool`. You need to either wrap the `map` in `or` or use `any`.

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly, the error you get tells you exactly what is wrong: You get a list of `Bool`s on the right side of `||`. So you need to process the result list from the `map` further, e.g. by applying `and` or `or` (probably the latter one). See http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/haskell98/latest/doc/html/List.html#v:or